# Change onclick event with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, events, attachment

I have this:

```
function tp_visible(action){
    if(action==1){
        document.getElementById("tp").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("tp_action").onclick='tp_visible(0);
        return false;';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("tp").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("tp_action").onclick='tp_visible(1);
        return false;';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Why isn't the above changing the `onclick` event?

I use [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) and the event remains the same...

Here is the HTML:

```
<a
    id='tp_action'
    name='tp_action'
    href='#'
    onclick='tp_visible(1);
    return false;'
>Show info</a>
```

Comment: dont forget to accept answer if it works for you

Answer (score 10):

The check below will work for you because you cannot assign a string value to the handler `onclick`.

```
function tp_visible(action){
    if(action==1){
        document.getElementById("tp").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("tp_action").onclick= function ()
            { tp_visible(0); return false;};
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("tp").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("tp_action").onclick= function ()
            {tp_visible(1); return false; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting out with Javascript I suggest you get aquainted with one of the many excellent javascript libraries and never try to write this stuff for yourself again - it leads to loosing your mind.

- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [JQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [DoJo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/)

Also you could do worse than to purchase Javascript the Good Bits and watch the set of videos by [Douglas Crockford](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2009/03/doug-crockford-javascript-good-parts.html).