# javascript for the variant of calculator

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style, logic

I am working on the project to create one variant of calculator. Basically, I am storing all the user clicks (which may be number and operator like +,-) in an array and handing the array to the another function when user clicks "=". I am using javascript for this. The below is my code:

```
  var arr=[]; //array of every input from the user interface stored
var i=0; //number of input clicks from the user
var opPos=[]; //position of the operator as given by the user
var operAnd=[];//operands as given by the user
var disp='';

function clearval() {

// This function clears all the values stored in related array when C or CE is pressed

    document.getElementById("op").value=0;
    arr=[];
    i=0;
    opPos=[];
    operAnd=[];
    disp='';
}


//This Function get the value and supplies the array to calculating function

function getval(inp){

    if(inp!="=")

    {
    arr[i]=inp;
    disp=disp+inp;//for display in the screen of the output screen
    document.getElementById("op").value=disp;

        if (typeof inp!="number"){
        opPos.push(i);
        operAnd.push(inp);
        }
    i++;
    }

    else
    {
    var newInput=assembler(arr,opPos,operAnd);
    clearval();
    getval(parseFloat(newInput,10));
    }

}


//<!------This Function calculates based on array, operator position and operands------!>



function assembler(num_array,opPos,operAnd){

var num='';
var numCollect=[];
var posCount=0;
for(var j=0;j<num_array.length;j++){
if (j==opPos[posCount]) {
    numCollect.push(parseFloat(num,10));
    num='';
    j++;
    posCount++;
}
else if (j>posCount) {

}
num=num+num_array[j];

}
num=parseFloat(num,10);
numCollect.push(num);
//document.getElementById("op").value= numCollect;
var newInput=calculator(numCollect,operAnd);
return newInput;
}



function calculator(target_num,operAnd) {

//    Not the nice solution but straightforward nonetheless
var result='';
for (var l=0;l<operAnd.length;l++) {
    result=result+target_num[l]+operAnd[l];
}
result=result+target_num[l];
document.getElementById("op").value=result + '=' + eval(result) ;
return eval(result);
}
```

I have html which has buttons like this:

```
<button class="num" onclick="getval(0)">0</button>
<button class="num" onclick="getval(1)">1</button>
<button class="num" onclick="getval(2)" >2</button>
<button class="num" onclick="getval(3)" >3</button>
......................... and so on
```

For the basic math, this code works fine and is not a problem. However, here is my problem from where I have hard time on thinking how to implement this. Say for example, I have a following button like this.

```
<button class='extra' onclick="Regression()"> Find Regression </button>
```

Now, I will have regression function which will ask user to input the regression type (1-linear, 2-quadratic and so on...this is just an example).

```
function regression(){

clearval();
document.getElementById("op").value=" Enter the degree of regression:";
```

which is basically asking user to enter the number and click '=' to enter into the program.
Now you can see my dilemma. Anything user inputs will be firstly processed by getval() which will pass the array to another function when user clicks '=', which is not what I will want in this case. To be clear, for this kind of case which I will have many such as std. dev or some kind of functions like this, I want the keypad to behave as normal keypad and pass the value to another function without doing normal calculator stuff as it was supposed to do.

Am I thinking this straight? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is what I would do(if I undestood right):

Change you button layout to this:

`<input type="button" class="num" value="0" />` *Removing the `onclick` event*

*Always better to use `input type="button"` than `<button>`.*

Create a function to bind events to the buttons:

```
function bindButtonEvent(func) {
    var buttons; // Here some way to get the button in a collection from the DOM tree
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { 
        buttons[i].onclick = function() { func(buttons[i]); } 
    }
}
```

With this you will got a function to change the `click` event of all your buttons. This will make your engine more flexible.

You will have to change your `getval` function a little to get the value by itself:

```
function getval(el){
    var inp = el.value;

    if(inp!="=")
```

So on the calculator load, you set the click function:

`bindButtonEvent(getval())`

When you want to call a custom behaviour function, you call the binding again:

```
function regression() {
    bindButtonEvent(function(el) {
        value = el.value;
        // Do things

        // When done, take bindings back.
        bindButtonEvent(getval());
    });

    clearval();
    document.getElementById("op").value=" Enter the degree of regression:";
}
```

**NOTE:** That is an ideia. I didn't tested the code. If you're interested on this and have errors on implementation, let me know, and we'll going fixing them.

Comment: This is actually nice way as far as I see it. But again pardon my ignorance, I cannot think of nice way of have buttons in array for ...var buttons...How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean sth like this: var buttons =document.getElementsByTagName('button');

Comment: Yes, something like that. But with my example, it will be to have like this: `var buttons =document.getElementsByTagName('input');` then find the buttons inside it.

Comment: My first question: when the calculator loads, I can then start with bindButtonEvent(getval())...You said I should modify the getval() function little. I don't know why I should touch it because now all the buttons have their function attached to getval() and I expect getval() to perform as it is now. Please correct me if I am wrong..Second question: I am having problem understanding your variable .el..what is it and also your implementation of regression function. Can you please clarify that to a novice like me. I am really happy that it is going great so far in positive direction. Thanks

Comment: You have noticed that I changed your button, so thats why you have to change the `getval`, because you're not passing the button value as a parameter to the function. In the new behaviour, the function will get the value by itself. The `el` is the element, the button itself, so the function will access the `value` attribute of the button the get the value, because you're not passing through the parameter anymore. Its clear?

Comment: Ah huh!, I understood that part now..Well, I really like your approach...However, I am now in a final part. When you have regression function, I am not understanding how you are passing function to the bindButtonEvent. Am I missing something or not understanding syntax. I would be glad if you can explain that to me and I will be really happy.

Comment: I hope I'm not confusing you, but with JS we can pass a function as a parameter. Look this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/rdf5Z/1/

Answer (score 2):

I think you could solve this by adding another function called `passval()`, which will contain much of the same logic as `getval()` in terms of parsing the input into a float, etc., but which doesn't ever push values onto your operand stack or call the `assembler` function.  It simply returns the button pushed as a nice float value to the `.extra` function that called it.

Then, as part of the logic in your `.extra` functions like `Regression()`, you would initially swap the `onclick` function for all of your buttons from `getval()` to `passval()`.  When the regression or other special function is complete, swap the buttons back to their default behavior.

Comment: How can I do the 'swap'? I am new to javascript and I don't know how I can change the onclick behavior of the button. Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: You'll need to grab all of the button elements from the DOM, probably using [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), and then change the onclick event for each of those elements.  There's a nice answer on how to do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244401/change-onclick-event-with-javascript-not-working).

Comment: All that said, if you're new to Javascript, doing all of this using plain old JS is making your life harder than it needs to be - I'd check out [jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).